# Llave compuesta MySQL

Tags: mysql

Necesito una llave compuesta para una base de datos de 10 campos, en la base de datos se registran escuelas mediante su cct(que sería la llave primaria) pero también necesito que se pueda registrar el mismo cct pero con un distinto turno(campo que debe estar relacionado con el cct), cualquier comentario se agradece.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que la tupla (cct, turno) sea irrepetible solo debes definirla  a esta como llave primaria de esta manera:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `escuela` (
  `cct` INT NOT NULL,
  `turno` INT NOT NULL,
  /** las demás columnas... */
  PRIMARY KEY (`cct`, `turno`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Si el problema es que ya tienes la tabla creada, entonces puedes editar la llave primaria de esta manera:

```
ALTER TABLE `escuela` 
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cct`, `turno`);
```

Así podrás tener la siguiente validación en tus registros:

```
cct | turno | ...
1   | 1     | ...  => Si
2   | 1     | ...  => Si
1   | 2     | ...  => Si
1   | 1     | ...  => No (Conflicto con el primer registro ingresado)
2   | 2     | ...  => Si
```

Comment: gracias por la respeusta, pero por desgracia no me ha funcionado, me sigue tomando como PK el cct y por lo tanto no me deja registrar aunque sea un turno distinto

Comment: Disculpa amigo, error mio, me has solucionado el problema, te lo agradezco, saludos.